# How to reference classes from other folder

Tags: swift, xcode, class

Today my mentor wanted me to create folders to store .swift files. I created 1 new folder (named "abc") in finder, and moved 3 files ("Album", "DataController" and "Song") in it. Then I dragged the folder to project and chosed "create copy if needed", "folder reference".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZm9q.png)

Now I couldn't reference the Song class in Song.swift. I did a research, found an answer that said I don't need to import or include file to use, the classes in swift are global, but I still received "Use of undeclared type" errors, as you can see.

My question is do I need to do any import or include like Java? if not then how can I reference class in Song.swift or other files in "abc" folder?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wrong screenshot!

Comment: In fact you can create folder by using Xcode. Select your files and right click, pick New group from selection. It also updates folder structure. Did you add Song to your app target?

Comment: @ridvankucuk can you explain a little bit more please? :D I'm new here

Comment: Not related to the issue but don't use `NSURL / NSData` in Swift. Use always `URL` and `Data` and delete the bridge casts.

Comment: @vadian I followed a guide and it worked so I didn't know it's a problem. Can you tell me more? :D

Comment: The *guide* is bad or outdated. Swift 3 introduces a lot of **structs** to replace the corresponding Foundation **classes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XCode9, Instead of creating a new folder in finder you can use Xcode for your folder structure. Pick the .swift files in Xcode project navigator menu. Then right click, select `new Group from Selection`. Then you will have a folder that contains your files. Also it updates project folder structure.

Comment: Yea seems like I created folder in a "stupid" way :D Thank you! But I have a side question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S76hO.jpg after create the folder like you said, all the reference works are good, but why do my classed have these question marks? Is that some kind of error or nothing?

Comment: They look like untracked files. Xcode is unavailable to track git stuffs sometimes. Can you check it on terminal, change directory to your project then type `git status`. You can see what is changed in your project.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I'm gonna try your solution tomorrow. Gotta go now!